# showing UIActivityIndicator on fetch of XML

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, grand-central-dispatch, uiactivityindicatorview

what im trying to do is parse an XML data and show it in my UITableView but the thing is it shows like after 2-3 seconds, im trying to include a UIActivityIndicator when the data loads and also im trying to include a gcd, but the thing is im new at this stuff so im really confuse on what to do or where do i posible put the gcd code.

that is my  .m file.

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize listTableView;

dispatch_queue_t myQueue;

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            return [[xmlParser listPopulated]count];

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    dataFileHolder *currentData = [[xmlParser listPopulated] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       CustomCellXMLClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCellXMLClass alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellXMLSample" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }



        NSString *nameLabel = [currentData nameOfCat];
        NSString *dataToCacheLabel = [myCache objectForKey:nameLabel];
        if(nameLabel != nil){
            dataToCacheLabel = [NSString stringWithString:nameLabel];
                if (dataToCacheLabel != nil) {
                    [myCache setObject:dataToCacheLabel forKey:nameLabel];
                    [cell.nameLabel setText:dataToCacheLabel];

                }
        }


        NSString *detailLabel = [currentData descriptionOfCat];
        NSString *stringToCache = [myCache objectForKey:detailLabel];
        if (detailLabel != nil) {
            stringToCache = [NSString stringWithString:detailLabel];
                if (stringToCache != nil) {
                    [myCache setObject:stringToCache forKey:detailLabel];
                    [cell.detailLabel setText:stringToCache];
                }
        }

        NSString *imageURL = [currentData imageLink];
        NSData *dataToCache;
            if (imageURL != nil) {

                dataToCache = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
                if (dataToCache != nil) {
                    [myCache setObject:dataToCache forKey:imageURL];
                    [cell.imageShow setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:dataToCache]];
                }
                else {
                    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i178.photobucket.com/albums/w255/ace003_album/190579604m.jpg"];
                    dataToCache = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
                    [myCache setObject:dataToCache forKey:imageURL];
                    [cell.imageShow setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:dataToCache]];
                }

            }



    return cell;

}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 78;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSString *title = @"Sample View";
    return title;

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;



dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^ {
    xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc]loadXMLByURL:@"http://www.irabwah.com/mobile/core.php?cat=0"];
    [self.activityIndicator performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
});

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how `XMLParser` works your current CGD block is ok for that. You wouldn't usually use `performSelectorOnMainThread` to return the UI interaction to the main thread but that's just a common convention thing.

Most of your problem could be coming from `dataWithContentsOfURL:` which you're calling on the main thread in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You might want to take a look at `SDWebImage` to help with that, but you could do it yourself with GCD too.

Comment: dont know whats the problem but still it just outputs a blank view. and im also thinking that the gcd i inserted in the viewDidLoad is the one making the problem as i tried to output how many rows is it returning by NSLog in numOfRowsInSection but it give 0, means no data have been fetch.

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` will not be called just because your XML finished loading. In your code block, I suggest before calling `stopAnimating` that you call `reloadData` on your UITableView; this will trigger a series of calls, first to `numberOfRowsInSection` and then to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` repeatedly. Try putting breakpoints in these functions so you can see the flow of execution.